# Calling remote Node.js via Javascript returns nothing

Tags: javascript, node.js

Node.js is running on a Linux server on port 8000.

This is a minimal set up as I am trying to build an application bit-by-bit.

On node.js we have 2 scripts:

```
// index.js

const express=require("express")
const server_route=require("./routing")
const app=express()
const cors = require("cors");

app.use("/",cors, server_route);

app.listen(8000,()=>{
  console.log("Server is Running on the port 8000")
})
```

Then we have the routing script:

```
//routing.js

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/startRoom?rname=.*&uname=.*', function(req, res, next) {
   console.log('Start Room');
   res.send('Start a Room');
   res.end();
});

router.get("/joinRoom?rname=.*&uname=.*",(req,res,next)=>{
   console.log('Join Room');
   res.send("Join room page");
   res.end();
})

router.get("/sendMesg?rid=.*&uid=.*&msg=.*",(req,res,next)=>{
   console.log('Send Mesg');
   res.send("Send Message page");
   res.end();
})

router.get("/*",(req,res,next)=>{
   console.log('Inv Page');
   res.send("Invalid page");
   res.end();
})

console.log( 'Router : ' + JSON.stringify(router) );

module.exports = router;
```

On the client the following Javascript is used to call this Node.js application.

```
<script>

function createRoom( uname, rname ) {

// chat.html?username=Saeed&room=r1

   var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      console.log('readyState: ' + this.readyState);
      console.log('status: ' + this.status);
      console.log('responseText: ' + this.responseText);
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         document.getElementById("room_content").innerHTML += this.responseText;
      }
   };

   var qurl = "http://10.0.0.94:8000/startRoom?rname=" + rname + '&uname=' + uname;
   console.log ('qUrl:' + qurl);
   xmlhttp.open("GET", qurl, true);
   xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>
```

Test:

```
<script>createRoom('<?= $usr_name ?>','<?= $room_name ?>');</script>
```

When I run this script in the browser I get nothing returned.

The XMLHttpRequest properties being printed on teh console lg are:

| Property | Value |
| --- | --- |
| readyState | 1 |
| status | 0 |

Short delay then

| Property | Value |
| --- | --- |
| readyState | 4 |
| status | 0 |

If I try the URL directly in the browser (or curl) it just hangs:

http://10.0.0.94:8000/startRoom?rname=Room1&uname=User2

I expecting/wanting to see the responseText of "Start a Room"

Answer (score 1):

should fix if you

```js
// index.js

const express=require("express")
const server_route=require("./routing")
const app=express()
const cors = require("cors");

app.use("/",cors, server_route.Routes);

app.listen(8000,()=>{
  console.log("Server is Running on the port 8000")
})
```

```js
./routing
  |--- index.js // create this new file for exporting Routes
  |--- routing.js

// index.js
const Routes = require('./routing');

module.exports.Routes = Routes;
```

```
//routing.js
...
module.exports = router;
```

Believe the problem is that require is loading up the file - while `app.use` *requires* that a module or function be provided.

Comment: Thanks. Should the `require('./routes');` in the `routing/index.js` be `require('./routing');` ? I made those changes but I still get the same result.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It didn't solve my issue but I've simplified the problem to a few line, and am positing another question rather than confuse matters by updating this question.